# Как запустить код Python с точками остановки в Visual Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Подскажите, как запустить код с точкой останова в Visual Code? Ставлю точки, запускаю в консоли, но всё равно они не реагируют

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в VS code в правом верхнем углу стрелка вниз, ее нажимаете и там Отладка файла Python
[image: ссылка]

Comment: Большое спасибо!